# x = x+1 != x++?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a really simple angular app. It just adds 1 to the value on ng-click.

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/josueespinosa/dZL3q/5/)

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-click="hello=hello+1">THIS WORKS ON CLICK: {{hello}}</div>
    <div ng-click="hello++">THIS DOESN'T: {{hello}}</div>
</div>
```

I expected to be able to '++' the value of a variable using ng-click, but apparently not. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: They both add one, what is the problem?

Comment: only one works.. the ++ operator isn't working upon click

Comment: @Bit hello++ does not add 1 in his fiddle

Comment: Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'undefined' not a primary expression at column null of the expression [hello++] starting at [hello++].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ng-click attribute expects a angular expression. While these expressions are javascript like, they are not javascript and you cannot do everything you can do in javascript in them. For more information, look at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

The important part from the link would be:

> Angular does not use JavaScript's eval() to evaluate expressions.
>   Instead Angular's $parse service processes these expressions.
>
> Angular expressions do not have access to global variables like
>   window, document or location. This restriction is intentional. It
>   prevents accidental access to the global state – a common source of
>   subtle bugs.
>
> Instead use services like $window and $location in functions called
>   from expressions. Such services provide mockable access to globals.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative for your code would be:

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope',

    function($scope) {
        $scope.hello = 0;
    $scope.sum = function(){
        $scope.hello++;
    }
    }]);
</script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-click="hello=hello+1">CLICKING HERE UPDATES VALUE: {{hello}}</div>
    <div ng-click="sum()">CLICKING HERE DOES NOT: {{hello}}</div>
</div>
```

Then the sum() function can be parsed by Angular's $parse service, but yes you have to write more code just to do a sum.